# Can we make solution file from cmake in one machine and run in another?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cmake

I have written a build system in cmake that works in linux and windows. In windows I generate solution file using cmake and use that solution file to build my project. The current solution file (generated by cmake) looks like it can only run from my machine. So I was wondering is there any way in cmake that can generate solution file in one machine and run in another.

Comment: "I was wondering is there any way in cmake that can generate solution file in one machine and run in another." - I know no such way. And I saw many phrases from the CMake developers that it is not intended to be changed in the future: CMake configuration creates a project which can be built only on the same machine (or on the identical one).

Comment: The visual studio project files (including sln) that cmake creates are horrendous mockeries of msbuild, doing everything in 8000 lines of code, when a hand-built msbuild file could be done in 20 lines of code. I would not consider those portable on any planet this side of the big bang.

Comment: Got it. Thank guys